# How to set custom REST port for apache ignite when ignite is started as a service in Opendaylight apache karaf?

Tags: ignite, apache-karaf, opendaylight

Opendaylight uses port 8080 which is the same as the default ignite REST http port. So i tried to change the port on which ignite listens for REST requests. Here is a java code snippet for this.

```
    System.setProperty("IGNITE_JETTY_PORT","7111");

    System.setProperty("IGNITE_JETTY_HOST","localhost"); 

    ignite = Ignition.start(config);
```

The above works fine and changes the ignite REST port when i run in eclipse. But fails when i start an ignite instance in apache karaf.

Comment: Possible that your port isn't available or dns server can't resolve the "localhost".  Could you please provide the fail log of apach ignite for investigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may try with the configuration xml file of ignite

```html
<property name="ConnectorConfiguration.jettyPath" value="config/ignite-rest.xml"/>
```

and in the ignite-rest.xml it like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Arg name="threadPool">
        <!-- Default queued blocking thread pool -->
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
            <Set name="minThreads">20</Set>
            <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>

    <New id="httpCfg" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
        <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
        <Set name="securePort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
        <Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
    </New>

    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server"/></Arg>
                <Arg>
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                        <Item>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                                <Ref refid="httpCfg"/>
                            </New>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Arg>
                <!--
                    Note that in order to override local host and port values,
                    system properties must have names IGNITE_JETTY_HOST and
                    IGNITE_JETTY_PORT accordingly.
                -->
                <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="IGNITE_JETTY_HOST" default="localhost"/></Set>
                <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="IGNITE_JETTY_PORT" default="9090"/></Set>
                <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
                <Set name="reuseAddress">true</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Set name="handler">
        <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <Set name="handlers">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                    <Item>
                        <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>

    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

You could change the port in the configuration file as you like,

and then start your ignite like:

ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfigPath);

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is working now. The issue was that i was getting a 'ClassNotFound' Exception as the ignite-core jar was unable to access a class from ignite-rest-http.

Answer (score 0):

You can change OpenDaylight's NB REST port if that would help. See the example provided by upstream configuration management tooling like puppet-opendaylight ([docs](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/packaging/puppet-opendaylight.git;a=blob;f=README.markdown;h=5915f399a1b6274c9ec496ac4d54e0cc3404c586;hb=HEAD#l129), [config logic](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/packaging/puppet-opendaylight.git;a=blob;f=manifests/config.pp;h=d6ad9eadd598fcd8d7372ce24deb4361ef0835d6;hb=HEAD)).