# How to change jetty port for Apache Ignite

Tags: jetty, ignite

I have a server running on port 8080 already which I can't disable, how do I change the jetty port from 8080 to something else?

I have already referred to [How to set custom REST port for apache ignite when ignite is started as a service in Opendaylight apache karaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860961/how-to-set-custom-rest-port-for-apache-ignite-when-ignite-is-started-as-a-servic) but it's not working for me.

I am running 2.7 version of Apache Ignite

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to specify `-DIGNITE_JETTY_PORT=XXXX` JVM-options?

Comment: Working thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using Binary Distribution

```
ignite.sh -v -J-DIGNITE_JETTY_PORT=<port> config/config.xml
```

Using Maven

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java DIGNITE_JETTY_PORT=<port> -jar ignite-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

For more details refer [this](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/multi-cluster-support) link